# How to customize category field text in kendo chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to customize the category field text of my Kendo Chart.
The text is too long so I wanted to make part of it bold to distinguish what was written
The Chart looks like this: [What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCtHE.jpg)


But what I want should look like this: [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdhxG.png)

My code for the chart looks like this:

```
var seriesConfig = [{
                field: "Duration",
                categoryField: "AlarmDescription",
                axis: "duration",
                name: textJSLayout["Duration"],
                type: seriesType,
                tooltip: {
                    template: "${series.name} : #=mpm.functionHelper.time.getFormattedTime(value)#" +
                    "<br> #=textJS['PercentageString']# : ${dataItem.Pareto} %" +
                    "<br> #=textJSLayout['Occurrences']# : ${dataItem.Occurrences} "
                },
                labels: {
                    template: "${dataItem.Occurrences}",
                    visible: true
                }
            }];
```

I also tryed using a template but it looks like there is no such a thing for the categoryField...
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see you doing this would be to leverage the categoryAxis' Label's Visual property: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels#categoryaxislabelsvisual

You would do this by appending the text with a new kendo.drawing.Text with bolded font. See this example: https://dojo.telerik.com/oGulOZim

The issue that you will run into is **when** to break the bolding font and when to start the normal font. That will need to take some trial and error on your part.